# Media queries not working with css modules

Tags: media-queries, react-css-modules

I'm trying to apply a media query with a css module with no success. The class I'm aiming for is `.Burger` and I'm using `Burger.module.css` to implement it as so:

**Burger.module.css**

```
.Burger {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: scroll;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
};

@media (min-width: 1000px) and (min-height: 700px) {
    .Burger {
        width: 700px;
        height: 600px;
    };
};
```

**Burger.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Burger.module.css';
import BurgerIngredient from './BurgerIngredient/BurgerIndgredient';

const Burger = ( props ) => {
    return (
        <div className={classes.Burger}>
            <BurgerIngredient type={'bread-top'}/>
            <BurgerIngredient type={'meat'}/>
            <BurgerIngredient type={'cheese'}/>
            <BurgerIngredient type={'bread-bottom'}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Burger;
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you get any errors? is any styling being applied from your CSS module?

Comment: No errors and the styling is applied. But when the resolution changes the media-query isn't being applied.

Comment: I've made a quick codesandbox with your code. [link](https://vqyse.csb.app/) and it definitely works in that. Can you identify anything different in your own code?

Comment: It was the semicolon!! I removed all the semicolons after the curly braces in the css and it worked. 1 - Thanks! ; 2 - Why?